# New to Jquery. What don't I understand with this code? Show/Hide

Tags: jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.targetDiv').hide();
  $('.show').click(function () {
     $('.targetDiv').hide();
     $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
  });

  $('.hide').click(function () {
     $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();

  });
</script>
<div class="buttons">
  <a  class="show" target="1">Option 1</a>
  <a  class="show" target="2">Option 2</a>
  <a  class="show" target="3">Option 3</a>
  <a  class="show" target="4">Option 4</a>
  <a  class="hide" target="1">Close 1</a>
  <a  class="hide" target="2">Close 2</a>
  <a  class="hide" target="3">Close 3</a>
  <a  class="hide" target="4">Close 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It works on Jfiddle, but it won't work properly when I try to do it as such.

1. Saving as HTML file.
2. Saving in same file.
3. Downloaded development package from Jquery.com (saved it as `jquery-1.9.1.js`)

Any information will be added on request. Should I be saving one file as HTML and the other as JS and linking them?

Comment: You forgot the http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: you have to wrap all code inside `$(function(){..})..`.In jsfiddlle it's already wrapped when you select type as `onload or onDOMReady`

Comment: @BradM I would be freaking out if I saw anyone using IE6 :P

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($)-----}); - Thank you for the help on this one. jQuery is a bit different in how it acts. Can I give you rep some how? First time on this site.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs as soon as it is loaded.  In this case it will load before the page is ready.  That's why JavaScript provides events to let us know when a page is loaded.

jQuery gives us nice functions to help with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // CODE
});
```

You will often see this as well:

```
$( function() {
    // CODE
});
```

This is shorthand for `.ready()`, but is basically the same thing.  Both will wait until the DOM has loaded before executing the code within.  The reason your code works on jsfiddle, is because it wraps the code automatically for you by default (look at the options in the menu on the left, you will see `onLoad` as the selected option).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your JavaScript code (the stuff between the non-jQuery `script` tags) with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I would vote this up, but I need 15 rep as required.

Answer (score 0):

of course if you want to code on jQuery script you must make another jquery scipt. the one that you download is script jquery api script